# Is there a way to directly access the color of a pixel of the display in Android?

Tags: android, pixel

Do you know if there is a way to get, at some point during the execution of an application, an information of the colors of all the pixels (or one pixel, it's indifferent)?
The thing I need to get the average color of the entire display at a particular instant.
I only found solutions that use screenshots of the display, but this thing takes time for the computation.
Practically, even if there is, I would do something like:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(this.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int pixel = display.getPixel(x,y);
int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your root view as a bitmap and then sample pixels.

For example:

```
View myLayout = findViewById(R.id.myRootLayout);
myLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = myLayout.getDrawingCache();
myLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

//sample a pixel
int color = bitmap.getPixel(20,20);
```