# Retrieving current text color with Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm working on adding night mode support to an Android application written in Xamarin.  One thing I will need to do is update the text color in several WebView controls.  The path I'm on requires that I retrieve the current text color in code.  So far, I've tried two techniques.

First:

```cs
var typedValue = new Android.Util.TypedValue();
Theme.ResolveAttribute(Android.Resource.Attribute.TextColor, typedValue, true);
var drawable = Application.Context.GetDrawable(typedValue.ResourceId);
var color = ((Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable) drawable).Color;
```

Second:

```cs
var attrs = new[] {Android.Resource.Attribute.TextColor};
var ta = ApplicationContext.ObtainStyledAttributes(Android.Resource.Style.TextAppearance, attrs);
var color = ta.GetColor(0, Color.Transparent);
```

The first one works for "ColorPrimary", which I've overridden in my styles.xml file, but throws an exception for TextColor, which is using the default style.  The second one returns a value, but it is the wrong value.

Is there a straight forward technique for retrieving colors within a style?

Update:

I did come up with a workaround.  On a page with a `TextView`, I'm capturing the `CurrentTextColor` property and storing the value in a static field in a helper class.  When I'm rendering out the html to go in my `WebView` i'm then using that stored value to set text color.  It is not as elegant as accessing the style directly, but it is working.  Fortunately, there is always a case in my app where a `TextView` is displayed before any `WebView`.

Comment: You can  try to access the color of a pixel of the display in android directly like this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444534/is-there-a-way-to-directly-access-the-color-of-a-pixel-of-the-display-in-android

Comment: Interesting way of getting information, but that wouldn't work for me.  I would have to know exactly where the line on a piece of text is on the screen in order to capture its value.

Comment: Based on my research, I cannot find a way to achieve that.